# R: Find object by name in deeply nested list

Tags: r, nested-lists

## Problem

I would suppose that this should be a common problem, yet I couldn't find a solution for it:

Let's assume a deeply nested list, such as:

```
my_list <- list(
  "first_node" = list(
    "group_a" = list(
      "E001" = 1:5,
      "E002" = list(
        "F001" = 6:10,
        "F002" = 11:15
      )
    ),
    "group_b" = list(
      "XY01" = list(
        "Z1" = LETTERS[1:5],
        "Z2" = LETTERS[6:10],
        "Z3" = list(
          "ZZ1" = LETTERS[1],
          "ZZ2" = LETTERS[2],
          "ZZ3" = LETTERS[3]
        )
      ),
      "YZ" = LETTERS[11:15]
    ),
    "group_c" = list(
      "QQQQ" = list(
        "RRRR" = 200:300
      )
    )
  ),
  "second_node" = list(
    "group_d" = list(
      "L1" = 99:101,
      "L2" = 12
    )
  )
)
```

## Desired Output

I want to retrieve elements by their name, that might be located at an unknown level of depth in that list. Importantly, I only want that specific element and it's children, not the parents.

For example, searching `my_list` for `"XY01"` should yield:

```
XY01 = list(
  "Z1" = LETTERS[1:5],
  "Z2" = LETTERS[6:10],
  "Z3" = list(
    "ZZ1" = LETTERS[1],
    "ZZ2" = LETTERS[2],
    "ZZ3" = LETTERS[3]
  )
)

> str(XY01)
List of 3
 $ Z1: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ Z2: chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
 $ Z3:List of 3
  ..$ ZZ1: chr "A"
  ..$ ZZ2: chr "B"
  ..$ ZZ3: chr "C"
```

## Previous attempts

Initially I want to use `rapply()` to do the job, but it seems that I wouldn't be able to access `names()` for the current iteration. My second attempt was writing a custom recursive function:

```
recursive_extract <- function(haystack, needle){

    lapply(names(haystack), function(x){
      if (needle %in% names(haystack[[x]])) {
        return(haystack[[needle]])
      } else {
        recursive_extract(haystack[[x]], needle)
      }
    }) %>% setNames(names(haystack))
}
```

...which also seems problematic, since `lapply()` will always give back the same object, even if `NULL` is returned, so the parental structure follows along.

I've been looking into the `purrr` and `rlist`-packages for a convenient function, but it seems that most of them don't support recursion (?).

## Bonus Challenge

After extracting the desired element, I would ideally want to choose how many child-levels to return. For instance:
`desired_func(haystack, needle, get_depth = 1)` for the previous example would result in:

```
XY01 = list(
  "Z1" = LETTERS[1:5],
  "Z2" = LETTERS[6:10]
)

> str(XY01)
List of 2
 $ Z1: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ Z2: chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
```

Very grateful for help! :)

Comment: regarding expected output: what if there are multiple elements with the same name at different places, and potentially different amount of depth? or if a child has the same name as the parent ;)

Comment: @akrun I've updated the desired output

Comment: @BerndKonfuzius right, forgot to mention that: Single-match would be fine, since in my particular case I can guarantee that all names are unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a function that will return the first match if found

```
find_name <- function(haystack, needle) {
 if (hasName(haystack, needle)) {
   haystack[[needle]]
 } else if (is.list(haystack)) {
   for (obj in haystack) {
     ret <- Recall(obj, needle)
     if (!is.null(ret)) return(ret)
   }
 } else {
   NULL
 }
}

find_name(my_list, "XY01")
```

We avoid `lapply` so the loop can break early if found.

The list pruning is really a separate issue. Better to attack that with a different function. This should work

```
list_prune <- function(list, depth=1) {
  if (!is.list(list)) return(list)
  if (depth>1) {
    lapply(list, list_prune, depth = depth-1)
  } else  {
    Filter(function(x) !is.list(x), list)
  }
}
```

Then you could do

```
list_prune(find_name(my_list, "XY01"), 1)
```

or with pipes

```
find_name(my_list, "XY01") %>% list_prune(1)
```

Comment: Is the `list_prune` function supposed to retrieve the index of the element in the list?

Comment: @Julien No. `list_prune` does not return indexes. It takes a list and returns a new list removing any entires that are nested beyond a certain depth level. It was for the "bonus" part of the question.

Comment: How do you retrieve the indices of the matched variable ?

Comment: @Julien I guess you could adapt this answer to keep track of the indexes with: https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/685e62e2f16461dcd6de142596b6bad6

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (an extension of base-`rapply`).

First, look up the position of `XY01` in the nested list:

```r
library(rrapply)

(XY01_pos <- rrapply(my_list, 
                    classes = "list",
                    condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "XY01", 
                    f = function(x, .xpos) .xpos, 
                    how = "flatten")[[1]])
#> [1] 1 2 1
```

Here, we make use of the `.xname` and `.xpos` arguments which evaluate to the name and position of the list element under evaluation. `how = "flatten"` returns a flattened version of the pruned list, in this case containing only the position of `XY01`.

Second, return the sublist by ordinary subsetting of the nested list:

```
str(my_list[[XY01_pos]])
#> List of 3
#>  $ Z1: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#>  $ Z2: chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
#>  $ Z3:List of 3
#>   ..$ ZZ1: chr "A"
#>   ..$ ZZ2: chr "B"
#>   ..$ ZZ3: chr "C"
```

For the bonus challenge we can make another call to `rrapply` applied to the sublist `my_list[[XY01]]` returning a pruned list containing only nodes that have a depth smaller or equal to a pre-specified maximum depth:

```r
maxdepth <- 1
rrapply(my_list[[XY01_pos]], condition = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) <= maxdepth, how = "prune")
#> $Z1
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
#> 
#> $Z2
#> [1] "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

Here `length(.xpos)` evaluates to the depth of the list element under evaluation, so we return only nodes that satisfy `length(.xpos) <= maxdepth`.

---

NB: we could also directly return the children of `XY01` with a single call to `rrapply` by setting `how = "prune"`:

```r
str(rrapply(my_list, classes = "list", condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "XY01", how = "prune"))
#> List of 1
#>  $ first_node:List of 1
#>   ..$ group_b:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ XY01:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ Z1: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#>   .. .. ..$ Z2: chr [1:5] "F" "G" "H" "I" ...
#>   .. .. ..$ Z3:List of 3
#>   .. .. .. ..$ ZZ1: chr "A"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ ZZ2: chr "B"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ ZZ3: chr "C"
```

But this would contain the complete node paths starting from the root instead of starting from the `XY01` node.