# How to pull out an element of a nested list in R that corresponds to the name of an entry?

Tags: r

I have nested set of lists that looks like

```
Example_List = list(Object=list(list(name="A",value=0.1),list(name="B",value=0.5),list(name="C",value=2)))

> Example_List
$Object
$Object[[1]]
$Object[[1]]$name
[1] "A"

$Object[[1]]$value
[1] 0.1


$Object[[2]]
$Object[[2]]$name
[1] "B"

$Object[[2]]$value
[1] 0.5


$Object[[3]]
$Object[[3]]$name
[1] "C"

$Object[[3]]$value
[1] 2
```

I would like to retrieve the value in the list of lists that corresponds to a given name. For example, if it was `name="B"`, the value to retrieve would be `0.5`. One way to do this is to search for the name index by using multiple `lapply` functions, then use that index (`2`) to retrieve the value.

Is there a more elegant solution in R?

Comment: What's wrong with `lapply(Example_List$Object, \(x) if (x[['name']] == 'B') x[['value']])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
xy <- sapply(Example_List[[1]], as.data.frame, simplify = FALSE)
xy <- do.call(rbind, xy)
xy
  name value
1    A   0.1
2    B   0.5
3    C   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably simpler ways of solving this but the recursive function below does the job.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400176/r-find-object-by-name-in-deeply-nested-list) may also be useful.

```r
Example_List = list(Object=list(list(name="A",value=0.1),
                                list(name="B",value=0.5),
                                list(name="C",value=2)))


find <- function(L, name) {
  if(is.list(L)) {
    if(any(names(L) == 'name')) {
      if(L[['name']] == name) {
        return(L[['value']])
      } else NULL
    } else {
      for(ll in L) {
        out <- Recall(ll, name)
        if(!is.null(out)) return(out)
      }
    }
  } else L
}
find(Example_List, 'A')
#> [1] 0.1
find(Example_List, 'B')
#> [1] 0.5
find(Example_List, 'C')
#> [1] 2

# this one doesn't exist in the list
f <- find(Example_List, 'X')
print(f)
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to first convert the nested list into a rectangular data.frame, after which filtering by name/value is easy. For instance,

```
## tidyverse
dplyr::bind_rows(Example_List[[1]])
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.1
#> 2 B       0.5
#> 3 C       2

## data.table
data.table::rbindlist(Example_List[[1]])
#>    name value
#> 1:    A   0.1
#> 2:    B   0.5
#> 3:    C   2.0
```

For deeper nested lists we can also use `rrapply()`:

```
rrapply::rrapply(Example_List, how = "bind")
#>   name value
#> 1    A   0.1
#> 2    B   0.5
#> 3    C   2.0
```

To filter values by name would then simply be a matter of e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(Example_List[[1]]) |>
  filter(name == "A")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.1
```