# Extracting value by name recursively

Tags: r, recursion

I'm trying to make a function to get values by name recursively. Here's what I've tried but I'm not sure why the loop doesn't stop when there's a match. I'm looking for a base R solution.

```r
pick <- function(x, name) {
  out <- c()
  for (i in names(x)) {
    if (i == name) {
      out <- x[[i]]
      break
    } else if (is.list(x[[i]])) {
      pick(x[[i]], name)
    }
  }
  out
}

list(
  `1` = list(
    A = list(
      a = "a value",
      b = "b value"
    ),
    B = list(
      c = "c value"
    )
  )
) |> 
  pick("a")
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400176/r-find-object-by-name-in-deeply-nested-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You return `out`, but you aren't assigning the result of your recursive `pick` call into `out`, so it is skipped.
2. If the recursive call finds something, you should likely `break`.

```r
pick <- function(x, name) {
  out <- c()
  for (i in names(x)) {
    if (i == name) {
      out <- x[[i]]
      break
    } else if (is.list(x[[i]])) {
      out <- pick(x[[i]], name)       # CHANGE
      if (length(out)) break          # ADD
    }
  }
  out
}

list(
  `1` = list(
    A = list(
      a = "a value",
      b = "b value"
    ),
    B = list(
      c = "c value"
    )
  )
) |>
  pick("a")
# [1] "a value"
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to assign the recursive call when making the example. That would have still returned `NULL`. The `length(out)` condition is what makes it work.